# Chrome never translate not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate

Since a few days Chrome, both on Android and on Windows, keeps on suggesting translating a language to English (I have both in english but I am Italian and often visit Italian sites). The never translate Italian setting does not work, in Chrome it's even selected in the popup on the right side of the address bar, still on both platforms the translation popup always appear. It is just me?

Answer (score 2):

Answer for Windows.

Enter in Chrome the address of `chrome://translate-internals`.
Check on top-left under "Languages not translated" if you see your language,
which is `it` for Italian.

If the language is in the list, report the problem to the Chrome developers
as a bug.

If the language is not in the list, you may force-put it in by editing the file
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`
and set the `translate_blocked_languages` item to look something like:
`"translate_blocked_languages":["it"]`.

Comment: Thanks, it's in the list there, so this seems like a bug. Funny though, there is a language not translated new and old, only the new list is populated, maybe it's related.

Comment: In my case, the old list is also empty, but for some reason "never translate" works for me. If your problem is just with specific websites, it's possible that these sites do not declare their language or that their IP address is not in Italy (I don't know which method Chrome uses for deciding on the document's language).